# Problems bulk insert elasticsearch curl powershell

Tags: powershell, curl, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I'm following the tutorial loading sample data: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-load-dataset.html
When I try to bulk insert the data in powershell
'curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary "@shakespeare.json"'

I get the following error

> PS C:\Development\elasticsearch-5.4.1\importdata> curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary "@shakespeare.json"
>   Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" value of type "System.St
>   ring" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
>   At line:1 char:9
>   + curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/s ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

I've tried several things, read the bulk api documentation but with no result

Here're some examples of the content of the json file:

{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"act","_id":0}}
{"line_id":1,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":"","line_number":"","speaker":"","text_entry":"ACT I"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"scene","_id":1}}
{"line_id":2,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":"","line_number":"","speaker":"","text_entry":"SCENE I. London. The palace."}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":2}}
{"line_id":3,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":"","line_number":"","speaker":"","text_entry":"Enter KING HENRY, LORD JOHN OF LANCASTER, the EARL of WESTMORELAND, SIR WALTER BLUNT, and others"}

Comment: The structure of the json data is different when using bulk injection, you basically need to add the index/type/id as part of the json: there is more info here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/docs-bulk.html

Comment: also you are using unix/curl litterally in powershell/Invoke-WebRequest, you should use Invoke-RestMethod instead imo.

Comment: finally the URI should be `localhost:9200/_bulk`..these comments wont solve it all since I didn't see the sharespeare.json file, but it should get you closer.

Comment: I added some example lines of the shakespeare.json file. Everything seems correct. I tried the Invoike-RestMethod but no result

Comment: Does anybody know why I get this exception 'Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" value of type "System.St ring" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary"'

Comment: try with an empty header initialized as `$header = @{}` (empty hash-table)

Comment: no result :-(  PS C:\Development\elasticsearch-5.4.1\importdata> invoke-restmethod "$header = @{}" -XPOST 'localhost:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty' -
-data-binary "@shakespeare.json"

Comment: No, `$header = @{}` is the definition of a variable, that you pass to invoke-restmethod via the -Headers parameters. Looks to me like you need to read about PowerShell before attempting something as complex as ElasticSearch bulk inserts, which will require advanced knowledge such as regex, parsing, array management, etc...

Comment: It's correct that I should read more about Powershell. It's that I'm following the turorial (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-load-dataset.html) to see the basics of elasticsearch. They offered the curl statements (fe 'curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @shakespeare.json') to load the bulk data.

Comment: Yes, however that is the original curl command used in a unix system. Even though powershell has an alias called curl, it actually points to a cmdlet called `Invoke-WebRequest` and that one has nothing in common with curl.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. No I understand it better. I've found a way to call the bulk api but I can get the data correctly in the body 'PS C:\Development\elasticsearch-5.4.1\importdata> curl -H @{"Content-Type" = "application/x-ndjson"} -Method POST 'http:
//localhost:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty' -body "@shakespeare.json"' Now I get an error from the api so the call succeeded. I get the same error if a try to insert incorrect data in the Kibana console

Comment: curl : {
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason" : "Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason" : "Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
At line:1 char:1
+ curl -H @{"Content-Type" = "application/x-ndjson"} -Method POST 'http ...

Comment: Found the solution, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Because I used curl on windows and with powershell, I had to translate

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @shakespeare.json
```

to

```
PS C:\Development\elasticsearch-5.4.1\importdata> $postParams = @"
>> {"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"act","_id":0}}
>> {"line_id":1,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":"","line_number":"","speaker":"","text_entry":"ACT I"}
>>
>> "@

PS C:\Development\elasticsearch-5.4.1\importdata> curl -H @{"Content-Type" = "application/x-ndjson"} -Method POST 'http://localhost:92
00/shakespeare/_bulk?pretty' -body $postParams
```

When I use the demo file, the bulk insert didn't succeeded but that's another problem

PS C:\Development\elasticsearch-5.4.1\importdata> $postParams = Get-Content "shakespeare.json"